# How to randomize an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have an array like this `$arr = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]` but I need a random version of this array, I was using the function `shuffle` like this `$random = shuffle($arr)` but this function just returns `true` and not a random version of the array.

Comment: Just print the array again you will be able to see the random version of your array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select random values from an array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639161/how-do-i-select-random-values-from-an-array-in-php)

Comment: You were using the correct function `shuffle` but you do not need to assign the result - at least not to the same variable name, so simply `$res = shuffle( $arr );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

> This function shuffles (randomizes the order of the elements in) an array. It uses a pseudo random number generator that is not suitable for cryptographic purposes.

The reason why you are getting `true` is because the `shuffle` function randomizes the elements correctly.

The array is passed by reference and not by value which mean that the next time you access the array it should be randomized

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do as this way you will get a result.

`$input = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9];
shuffle($input);
print_r($input);`